# Mathematica package for supergravity and string theory

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mathematical-software, string-theory, clifford-algebras, tensor

I am looking for a Mathematica package that can manipulate tensors for supergravity, string theory or M-theory. I am particularly looking for a package that can do spinor and Clifford algebra computations. Also, I would like this package to be able to do wedge and hodge dual, and other computation relating to forms.
Can anyone suggest a specific one? I looked for atlas2, but it seems I have to pay to use it without a trial version.

Comment: You may also be interested in the CAS cadabra and in the ctensor package for the CAS Maxima. These are all free and open-source.

Comment: You should also ask at the physics and Mathematica stackexchanges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try xact
http://www.xact.es/AVF/index.html
or see if http://sagemanifolds.obspm.fr/ for sage works for you.